# Is there any classic Christian writer who mentioned what color the Lake of fire is?

Tags: hell, books

Is it mentioned anywhere in Christian literature (especially in the older literature), that the [Lake of fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_of_fire) has a specific color, such as Black?

Comment: Since scripture does not state the fact, it would be supposition for anyone to guess at it. Therefore this is a matter of opinion, which would be off-topic on this site. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Welcome to SE-C. (Note: It would also be a conjecture to suppose that any writer _had_ written so, thus it is still a matter of opinion as to the _possibility_ of such writing. Otherwise, we would face a host of interminable questions about every possibility in all the literature of the entire world.)